# To change tabular data to a different format in R

Tags: r

Change below data

```
pos BZ_SP   BZ_SP_m1    BZ_SP_m2    CL_SP   CL_SP_m1    CL_SP_m2
1   -300000 2   3   2540544 1   2
2   0   0   0   -118621 3   4
```

to look this way

```
CurveGroup  SpreadId    SpreadMonth1    SpreadMonth2    Position
BZ_SP   1   2   3   -300000
CL_SP   1   1   2   2540544
BZ_SP   2   0   0   0
CL_SP   2   3   4   -118621
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) will help you work through your challenge. We are willing to help you solve a specific problem, not to do the work for you.

Comment: I tried the melt option 
data_test_SP <- melt(readxl::read_excel("C:/Risk_R/Postion_20171110.xlsx", sheet.names[1]), id.vars=1, value.name="Position", variable.name="CurveGroup")
but I am not able to slice the data in the format I required

Comment: Please add your attempts to your question.

Answer (score 1):

`gather` the input into long form and then separate the `variable` into `Curvegroup` and `suffix`.  `spread` it back out to wide form.  Rename and rearrange the columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
   gather(variable, value, -pos) %>% 
   separate(variable, c("CurveGroup", "suffix"), sep = 5, fill = "right") %>% 
   spread(suffix, value) %>%
   select(CurveGroup, SpreadId = "pos", SpreadMonth1 = "_m1", SpreadMonth2 = "_m2", 
     Position = "V1")
```

giving:

```
  CurveGroup SpreadId SpreadMonth1 SpreadMonth2 Position
1      BZ_SP        1            2            3  -300000
2      CL_SP        1            1            2  2540544
3      BZ_SP        2            0            0        0
4      CL_SP        2            3            4  -118621
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
DF <- structure(list(pos = 1:2, BZ_SP = c(-300000L, 0L), BZ_SP_m1 = c(2L, 
  0L), BZ_SP_m2 = c(3L, 0L), CL_SP = c(2540544L, -118621L), CL_SP_m1 = c(1L, 
  3L), CL_SP_m2 = c(2L, 4L)), .Names = c("pos", "BZ_SP", "BZ_SP_m1", 
  "BZ_SP_m2", "CL_SP", "CL_SP_m1", "CL_SP_m2"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

**Update:** Simplified.

Comment: This is exactly what I a looking for. Thanks  Grothendieck.